# How to show the public key for a website certificate

Tags: ssl, go, ssl-certificate

I've created a Go program to connect to a website and get the certificates it uses. I'm not sure how to get the correct representation of the public key.

I can fetch the certificate and I can type check on Certificate.PublicKey. Once I understand it's rsa.PublicKey or ecdsa.PublicKey I'd need to print the hex representation of it.

```
switch cert.PublicKey.(type) {
case *rsa.PublicKey:
    logrus.Error("this is RSA")
    // TODO: print hex representation of key
case *ecdsa.PublicKey:
    logrus.Error("this is ECDSA")
    // TODO: print hex representation of key
default:
    fmt.Println("it's something else")
}
```

I'd expect it to print something like:

```
04 4B F9 47 1B A8 A8 CB A4 C6 C0 2D 45 DE 43 F3 BC F5 D2 98 F4 25 90 6F 13 0D 78 1A AC 05 B4 DF 7B F6 06 5C 80 97 9A 53 06 D0 DB 0E 15 AD 03 DE 14 09 D3 77 54 B1 4E 15 A8 AF E3 FD DC 9D AD E0 C5
```

Comment: Both of these key types are a composite of multiple values. Two numbers (one of which is very big) for RSA, and an elliptical curve (which is itself defined by six or so numbers) and a point on that curve (two big numbers) for ECDSA. There is no natural hex representation for either of those. You have to turn the keys into byte slices first ([x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#MarshalPKIXPublicKey)), which you can then hex encode, but that is unusual (PEM encoding is often used).

Comment: I tried this too but the hex encode didn't match the one I could see inspecting the cert via the browser (for www.google.com). Would you mind providing a snippet for both the hex and pen conversion, starting from the Certificate.PublicKey structure?

Comment: You are probably looking at "fingerprints", which are hashes of the whole certificate and signature, not just the public keys. See ramrunner's answer for how to compute them.

Comment: I'd say I'm actually interested in both. I'd like to compare the fingerprints (I'll look at the answer ramrunner gave), but I'd also like to print out the certificate. In my code I also tried using the MarshalPKIXPublicKey, but from there I'm not sure how to print the public key in pem format.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you are asking for the sha1 sum of the certificates involved.
here is a working example that asks for a host:port and prints the sums of the certificates involved

```
package main

import (
        "crypto/sha1"
        "crypto/tls"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        if len(os.Args) != 2 {
                log.Panic("call with argument of host:port")
        }
        log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)

        conf := &tls.Config{
                //InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        }
        fmt.Printf("dialing:%s\n", os.Args[1])
        conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", os.Args[1], conf)
        if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
        }
        defer conn.Close()
        for i, v := range conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates {
                //edit: use %X for uppercase hex printing
                fmt.Printf("cert %d sha1 fingerprint:%x \n", i, sha1.Sum(v.Raw))
        }
}
```

run as:

```
./golang-tls www.google.com:443
dialing:www.google.com:443
cert 0 sha1 fingerprint:34781c3be98cf958f514aecb1ae2e4e866effe34
cert 1 sha1 fingerprint:eeacbd0cb452819577911e1e6203db262f84a318
```

for general notions on SSL i have found [this stackexchange answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) to be extremely valuable.

Comment: The format string `"% X"` produces the format as asked in the question.